# SQL subquery to join the most recent plan for a client

Tags: sql, ms-access

In MS Access 365, I have two tables (TClients & TPlans) that I am trying to combine into a single Query (QClientsExtended).  Each client could have many or no associated entries on the TPlan list. In my final query, I would like it to list every client regardless of wether or not they have a plan, and give me the date and the details of the most recent plan, if there is one.

I've read all the relevant W3C reference pages, and looked at so many possible solutions, and i've struggled to turn them into something that works for this. It feels like it should be SO simple, I appreciate I'm probably missing a fundamental aspect of SQL coding.

**TClients**

```
ClientID    ClientFullName      ExternalAppts
1           Testy McTestFace    1
2           Clemence Closed     0
3           Nancy New Ref       3
4           Juan One Appt       0
```

**TPlans**

```
PlanID  ClientID    PlanDetails PlanDate
1       3           Plan 1      05-Dec-22
2       3           Plan 2      10-Dec-22
3       1           plan        10-Dec-22
4       4           nil         05-Dec-22
```

**Qclients Extended**

```
ClientID    ClientFullName      PlanDetails PlanDate    ExternalAppts
1           Testy McTestFace    Plan 2      10-Dec-22   1
2           Clemence Closed                             0
3           Nancy New Ref       plan        10-Dec-22   3
4           Juan One Appt       nil         05-Dec-22   0
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found a solution, but it feels incredibly clunky. I have made two Queries, one to find the most recent date for each client, and the second to Left Join this with the Client Table.  I'm sure this should be doable in a single query, but maybe it can't be done in Access.  Here are my two Queries:

**QlastPlan**

```SQL
SELECT t1.*
FROM TPlans AS t1 
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT [ClientID], 
    MAX(PlanDate) AS LastPlan 
  FROM TPlans 
  GROUP BY [ClientID])  
  AS t2 ON (t1.[PlanDate] = t2.LastPlan) AND (t1.[ClientID] = t2.[ClientID]);
```

**QClients**

```SQL
SELECT 
  TC.*, 
  QLP.PlanDetails, 
  QLP.PlanDate,
FROM TClients TC
LEFT JOIN QlastPlan QLP on TC.ClientID = QLP.ClientID;
```

So perhaps there's another option someone can suggest, but this is what I will run with for now.

Answer (score 0):

Try with a *Left Join*:

```sql
SELECT 
    TClients.ClientID, 
    TClients.ClientFullName, 
    TPlans.PlanDetails, 
    TPlans.PlanDate, 
    TClients.ExternalAppts
FROM 
    TClients 
LEFT JOIN 
    TPlans ON TClients.ClientID = TPlans.ClientID
GROUP BY 
    TClients.ClientID, 
    TClients.ClientFullName, 
    TPlans.PlanDetails, 
    TPlans.PlanDate, 
    TClients.ExternalAppts
HAVING 
    TPlans.PlanDate=
        (Select Max(PlanDate) From [TPlans] As T Where T.ClientID = TClients.[ClientID]) 
        OR 
        TPlans.PlanDate Is Null
```

Comment: Thankyou for the reply! When I launch the query, it asks me for the parameter value of TClients.PlanDate, and if I hit enter and leave it blank, I get the following: 

ClientID ClientFullName PlanDetails LastPlan ExternalAppts
1  Testy McTestFace p1     0

2  Clemence Closed      0

3  Nancy New Ref Plan 1    7
3  Nancy New Ref Plan 2    7
4  Juan One Appt      0

this gives all clients AND all plans, wheras I only want all clients & most recent plan. I'm struggling to understand why & when Access feels the need to ask for parameters, I feel like it shouldn't need to here?

Comment: oh wait, your code had a few minor errors but once I changed them to the following, it worked perfectly! 
`SELECT 
TClients.ClientID, 
TClients.ClientFullName, 
TPlans.PlanDetails, 
TPlans.PlanDate, 
TClients.ExternalAppts
FROM 
TClients 
LEFT JOIN 
TPlans ON TClients.ClientId = TPlans.ClientId

GROUP BY 
TClients.ClientID, TClients.ClientFullName, TPlans.PlanDetails, TClients.ExternalAppts, TPlans.PlanDate
ORDER BY TClients.ClientID;
`

Comment: Hang on, I've just tested this properly today, and it has the same problem as before; I'm getting 5 results instead of 4, it's including both Plans for Nancy New Ref

Comment: Yes. You could use a subquery to filter for the max. date.